# Why is AutoCloseable the base interface for Closeable (and not vice versa)?

Tags: java, api, interface

As far as I know, the [Closeable](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) interface was around from Java 1.5 and the [AutoCloseable](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) was introduced in Java 1.7.
What I am trying to understand is why Closeable **extends** AutoCloseable and not vice versa? 
Is this done because of backward dependency (not being able to change the Closeable interface) i.e. the need for AutoCloseable to have a wider exception than Closeable? Or is my logic just wrong and it should be that way?

Comment: Read the last sentence of the `AutoCloseable#close()` method's javadoc.

Comment: I think it has to be with an enhancement for Closeable superclasses, so that the JVM can auto close them on the new JDK versions. Since Closeable only defines that a class implements a close() method, but AutoCloseable would ensure to call the close method.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This way, all the user code which implemented `Closeable` automatically gets to implement `AutoCloseable`, which allows them to automatically benefit from the try-with-resources syntax.

Comment: With Closeable you can throw only IOException, while with AutoCloseable interface you can throw all the Exception

Answer (score 27):

@Sotirios Delimanolis's comment has nailed it.

The Java 7 team wanted a mechanism to label objects as be auto-closeable for the "try with resources" construct.  Unfortunately the API spec for the `Closeable.close()` method is too strict.  It requires the `close()` method to be idempotent ... but this is not necessary in the "try with resources" use-case.

So they introduced the `AutoClosable` interface with a less restrictive `close()` semantic ... and retro-fitted `Closeable` as a subtype of `AutoCloseable`.

The other thing is that `AutoCloseable.close()` is declared as throwing `Exception` rather than `IOException`.  This means that the `AutoCloseable` API is less restrictive than `Closeable` ... and given that it is effectively used as a *callback* API in try-with-resources, this makes it more flexible / more broadly applicable.  (The API can be used for resources that have nothing to do with I/O, but still might throw exceptions on close.)  The flip-side is that Java typing would not allow them to make such a change if the `close() throws Exception` method had been injected into the subtype.

---

The alternatives would have been:

- to restrict "try with resources" to resources with an idempotent close ... which limits its usefulness, or
- to retrospectively change the semantics of `Closeable.close()` ... which could lead to difficulties for folks porting older code to Java 7
- to retrospectively change the signature of `Closeable.close()` ... which would break binary compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

The `Closeable` interface was introduced in Java 5.
When `try-with-resources` (below is an example code) was introduced in Java 7, the language designers wanted to change some things but needed backward compatibility (all the code which is written in previous versions should not become obsolete with introduction of new functionalities) also so they created a Superinterface `AutoCloseable` with the rules they wanted.

An example of try with resources:

```
    try (NewResource a = NewResource.CreateResource();
{
    }
```

Above code is Try with resources. We can simply understand by this is that in this code we can declare a new variable itself in the try code and that variable can call upon other methods within the code. Apart from decreasing verbosity of `try` block this code also does not require a finally block, but the executing environment should be Java 7 or above. Although the finally is created by JVM itself.

`closeable` & `Autocloseable` interface contains just one method

```
void close()
```

While `close ()` method of `closeable` throws `IOException`, `Autocloseable`'s `close()` method throws `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

`Closeable` has some limitations, as it can only throw `IOException`, so it cannot be changed without breaking legacy code. 
So `AutoCloseable` was introduced, which can throw `Exception`.

`AutoCloseable` is to be used for applications using >JDK7.

As JDK7+ libraries use `AutoCloseable` and legacy code which implements `Closeable` still need to be compatible with JDK7+, 
it is made that Closeable extend AutoCloseable.

```
public interface Closeable extends AutoCloseable {
    public void close() throws IOException;
}
```

`AutoCloseable` was specifically designed to work with try-with-resources statements.
As `Closeable` extends `AutoCloseable`, try-with-resources can be used to close any resources that implement either Closeable or AutoCloseable.